# Solr DIH data import is not working for XML files

Tags: xml, tomcat, import, solr, dih

I have configured my solr dih to import the xml files and it was working for some time.
Then it suddenly stop working and I cannot make it to go anymore.
The dataimport is stating:

```
1 <str name="Total Rows Fetched">1</str> 
2 <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
3 <str name="Full Dump Started">2011-03-08 12:14:31</str>
4 <str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
```

The Tomcat catalina log is reporting:

```
INFO: [] webapp=/solr3 path=/select params={clean=false&commit=true&command=full-import&qt=/dataimport} status=0 QTime=0 
Mar 8, 2011 12:14:31 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
INFO: Starting Full Import
Mar 8, 2011 12:14:31 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
INFO: Read dataimport.properties
Mar 8, 2011 12:14:31 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder execute
INFO: Time taken = 0:0:0.63
Mar 8, 2011 12:15:38 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
INFO: Starting Full Import
Mar 8, 2011 12:15:38 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr3 path=/select params={clean=false&commit=true&command=full-import&qt=/dataimport} status=0 QTime=0 
Mar 8, 2011 12:15:38 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties
Mar 8, 2011 12:15:38 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder execute
INFO: Time taken = 0:0:0.15
```

The only thing it worned about is  "WARNING: Unable to read: dataimport.properties"

I tried to install Solr on another servers and PCs 3 more times and have same issue every time. It has the same behavier with examples I get from the Net and with my customized configs.

Hitting the wall with this. Can anybody please help?

Comment: The Dataimport reporting (wasnot posted properly in initial question):

<str name="Total Rows Fetched">1</str> 
<str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
<str name="Full Dump Started">2011-03-08 12:14:31</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>

Answer (score 0):

Post your dataimport.properties and schema.xml (only custom field declarations) files.

BTW, when you have formatted output use Code formatting when posting (it uses html tag **pre** to preserve whitespace).